# What does Facebook take into account when inferring Open Graph properties from an URL?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-like

I'm having a problem with the Facebook Like Button [here](http://develop-nuageloja.vtexcommerce.com.br/). Although the button works, it's fetching the wrong thumbnail to display on Facebook.

Since the website is a store and each product has its own like button, it's very important that the correct thumbnail is displayed on Facebook. I used the [Facebook Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to debug a product URL from the site. I hoped Facebook would grab the bigger, obviously main image of a product URL but it's fetching one of the related products thumbnail.

From what I've read in the docs, I should explicitly set `og:image` in the head of my document. However, I have no access to the back-end and I can only use JavaScript to dynamically generate a meta-tag. I've tried to do that but it seems worthless doing so since the URL is scrapped before any script is run.

I don't understand what rules Facebook is using to infer the value of `og:image`. On [another website](http://www.usereserva.com) that also doesn't have any meta-tags set, the main image of the product is being correctly scrapped. Why?

When, for whatever reason, one cannot declare any Open Graph properties, what can be done to improve the chances of Facebook's algorithm grabbing the desired image (or text)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should set `og:image` meta tags as part of the open graph protocol. When this fails, it simply defaults to all images via image html tags take into precedence. The very first image defined via `img` tag will be the first image pulled by facebook.

```
<html><body>
    <p style="background:url(img0.jpg);">hello</p>
    <img src="img1.jpg">
    <img src="img2.jpg">
    <p>bye</p>
    <img src="img3.jpg">
</body></html>
```

If the above sample code was your site, facebook would label img1, img2 and img3 as potential thumbnails and in that order if the user has the option to choose what image to specify.

So, just put your product picture first.

Comment: I think that's only part of the algorithm used. I've debugged two different URLs: [one that's fetching the correct image](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.usereserva.com%2FCAMISA_SPORT_XADREZ_CPUNHO_MC_0006811005%2Fp%23.UMA7DoN9KuI) and [other that is not](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdevelop-nuageloja.vtexcommerce.com.br%2Fsaia_zoe%2Fp).

The wrong image being fetched on the latter example is far from being the first in the DOM. It's not even the first in its own `<UL>`. I don't get it.

Comment: As long as you are not using open graph protocol on it, there's really no guarantee since there's no further defined API. First image simply has the highest probability. From previous testing, it did have tendencies to avoid certain pictures such as being too small or too big.